# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Auth":

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I have the following dependencies in my flutter (3.3.7) app:

```
...
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations: 
    sdk: flutter         
  firebase_core: ^2.1.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.4
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.0.4
...
```

On MacOS, I want to build it now for iOS Simulator, but It always fails to build. When I manually type pod repo update and then pod install, there seems to be a conflict of dependencies for Firebase SDK 9 and SDK10. However, how do I solve it? E.g. going back to firebase auth: 3.1.1 gives a bunch of other conflicts. ...

```
pod install
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '10.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Auth":
In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
Firebase/Auth (= 9.6.0)

In Podfile:
firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
Firebase/Auth (= 10.0.0)


You have either:
* out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
* changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Auth` inside your development pod `firebase_auth`.
  You should run `pod update Firebase/Auth` to apply changes you've made.
```

Any ideas? Or this simply a Firebase Flutter/SDK problem where I have to wait for a solution? (btw: Android Build is working fine)
Thanks

Comment: pod update repo

Comment: did, but no success...
also pod deintegrate.... pod repo update, not better.....

Comment: try `pod update` instead of `pod install`

Comment: yes did already, no success

Comment: Delete the Pods folder and delete Podfile.lock file... After that try pod update

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps

1. cd ios
2. pod update

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that deleting the `podfile.lock` file and then running `pod repo update` and `pod install` solved it for me.